# Chrome Uses Background Data Despite Its Background Data Has Been DISALLOWED in Android Setups

Tags: chrome-for-android, background-data

Android Chrome eats **LOTS** of background mobile data on my phone. This is despite the fact that in Android setups I **DISALLOWED** Chrome to use background data (i.e., Settings -> Connections -> Data usage -> Mobile data usage -> Chrome -> the toggle "Allow background data usage" is "off").

UPDATE: My mobile data usage comes from a single web site where I listen to audio books.  I keep only that single tab open in Chrome.  Normal data usage from that site is around 0.5 ... 1 MB foreground data per minute and zero background data.  However, on some random days (every 2-5 days) I find that Chrome used up LOTS of background data, at a rate around 10 ... 30 MB background data per minute.

Just happened another time today Sept 25, 2019, see the following two screenshots.  The time difference between them is 8 minutes.  In those 8 minutes, Chrome (with a single tab open), used 10 MB foreground data and **130 MB (!) of background data**.  This, despite the fact that **"Allow background data usage" toggle was "off"**.

[image: Screenshot_20190925-085418_Settings]
[image: Screenshot_20190925-090228_Settings]

See the attached image: a Sept. 18 2019 screenshot of data usage by Chrome. Note that between September 8th and 18th, Chrome used 1.8 GB background mobile data in addition to using 0.2 GB foreground mobile data. The toggle "Allow background data usage" has been "off" since before Sept. 8th.

My phone: Samsung S7 SM-G930T T-Mobile with latest T-Mobile stock Android 8.0 load.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: A screenshot of data usage by Chrome. Note that between September 8th and 18th, Chrome used 1.8 GB background mobile data in addition to using 0.2 GB foreground mobile data. The toggle "Allow background data usage" has been "off" since before Sept. 8th.]

Comment: Looks like you have a rogue script on a page... It can happen. That background data usage restriction is a little fuzzy, as even when tasks are not the active task you see, that doesn't necessarily mean they are in the background until the kernel decides they are. Sometimes an app can get stuck doing something and it never get's "in the background" from the kernel's perspective, even though it isn't right in front of you. Is this a consistent thing, or have you only seen it once? Honestly, I would clear data on Chrome, actively close tabs you don't need, and see if it continues.

Comment: @acejavelin, it is a somewhat consistent thing that started around 3 months ago. My monthly Chrome foreground mobile data usage was somewhat level in the last 4 months (0.5GB...1GB); background Chrome mobile data usage jumped from 0.9GB 4 months ago to 2.3GB...2.5GB in the last 3 months. My main Chrome mobile data usage over this whole period is listening to audiobooks from the same web site, roughly 20...30 hrs per month.

Comment: @acejavelin , I did have multiple Chrome tabs open. From now on I'll have only 1 tab open when listening audiobooks; I'll monitor data usage and will report my findings. Still I can't comprehend how Android (as shown in the screenshot in the OP) shows non-zero background data usage for Chrome while the slider "Allow background data usage" is in the "off" position.

Comment: Another spur of background data usage today: within 8 minutes, Chrome (with a single tab open where I listened to an audiobook), used 10 MB foreground data and 130 MB of background data.  This, despite the fact that "Allow background data usage" toggle was "off".

Comment: I would double check all 'Settings' in Chrome (three dots menu). There is for example a 'Preload pages for faster browsing and searching' in 'Privacy' which may be downloading closed tab content. Also in 'Sync and Google Services' are you syncing account data and/or sending usage statistics back to Google. individually each one may be a 'small' amount of data but collectively it may add up. Otherwise you'll have to setup a WiFi HTTP Proxy (like wireshark) to capture your data to see where it is going.

Comment: @Morrison I would use an app like [NetMonitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.secuso.privacyfriendlynetmonitorapp) to get an impression of the traffic coming in and out in a certain time. May be you installed accidentally an malicious add-on that now loads hundred of ads in the background (ad fraud).

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks, I've unchecked 'Preload pages for faster browsing and searching'. Under 'Sync and Google Services' I have the following checked on: 'Sync your Chrome data', 'Autocomplete searches and URLs', 'Safe browsing', and 'Make searches and browsing safer'; I'm going to leave them as is because I just don't believe any of them could cause 500 MB traffic per 1 hr. Setting a WiFi HTTP Proxy (like wireshark) is probably above my level...

Comment: @Robert thanks, I've added NetMonitor and will try to learn how to use it. It does show IPs to which an app is connected but unfortunately it's not showing traffic data at all. I have a [My Data Manager - Data Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm), it shows traffic per app per time period but unfortunately not by IP to which an app is connected -- _that_ would be the thing that I need!